# Angular Observable best approach for condition

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Assuming I'd like to be notified and consume an async pipe when it's populated
What would be the best approach for that.

```
 this.some_page = this.api.getReportPage();

        this.route.queryParams.subscribe(p => {
            this.checkIdQueryParam = p.checkId;
            /**
             * variable some_page is consumed via async pipe in the template and i'd like to be notified when it's consumed 
             * (or change the entire design if needed, e.g - not use async or something
             */

    });
```

The purpose is that when there's a query param , i'd like to invoke some action, but it depends on the some_page to be populated.

Comment: what does this.some_page do? what is the functionality?

Comment: just some entities page returning from the backend. the result is something like {'entities': [], size:1} or something similar.

Comment: Why dont you get the result from `this.api.getReportPage()` and then assign `this.some_page` in subscribe method and then execute other lines?

Answer (score 0):

You can use switchmap of rxjs

```
this.some_page = this.route.queryParams
        .pipe(switchMap((p) => {
          if (p.checkId) {
         
            return this.api.getReportPage();
          }
          return of([]);
        }))
```

Comment: nice idea. but that we'll actually change the assignment of some_page . I'd rather get notified when some_page is consumed in the template itself. I thought about subject and multicasting  but i don't want to handle the unsubscribe myself (which is why the some_page is actually consumed by | async pipe

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is called a "Side Effect" which should always be done by the `tap()` operator. It should be something like this:

```js
this.some_page$ = this.route.queryParams
  .pipe(switchMap((param) => {
      const checkId: string = param.checkId ?? '';
      return !checkId ? of([]) : this.api.getReportPage().pipe(
        tap((getReportRes) => {
          //invoke Actions
        })
      );
  }))
```

Comment: Nice! but does the line where you wrote "//invoke actions" return an observable also?

Comment: no, tap operator always returns void